# Trouble getting started with Metal shader compilation

Tags: metal

I'm having trouble getting started with Metal's shader compilation.

How to make a `MTLLibrary` that can link to a `MTLDynamicLibrary` (or `MTLLinkedFunctions`), in particular a library that declares `extern` functions that are to be resolved at runtime when providing `preloadedLibraries` (or `linkedFunctions`) in the compute pipeline descriptor? For example, I can compile the following to `air` using `xcrun metal` (with option `-c`), but then invoking `xcrun metallib` (even with option `--split-module-without-linking`) gives the error `LLVM ERROR: Undefined symbol: _Z3addjj`. In other words, how do I make a 'partially bound' metal library?

```cpp
// shader.h
extern uint add(uint a, uint b);
```

```cpp
/// shader.metal
#include "shader.h"
kernel void kernel_func(uint gid [[ thread_position_in_grid ]]) { add(gid,2); }
```

[WWDC2021](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2021/10229/) mentions this `extern` technique, but the [Dynamic Library Code Sample](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/metal/shader_libraries/creating_a_metal_dynamic_library?language=objc) from the previous year doesn't use `extern` (or the `installName`), so I don't make sense of it.

Answer (score 0):

When creating an executable library that uses a dynamic library, there are two points where you must include the dynamic library (I thought there was only one).
The process is different depending on whether the executable source is compiled at build or runtime. I'll describe for the case of runtime, because I haven't yet figured out the case for the executable library created from a `metallib` file.

1. The first point is when you compile the executable, where you must include the dynamic library in the `libraries` field of the `CompileOptions`. The library is there at this point just as a dummy, to check that you have a dynamic library that defines the declarations allowing for proper linkage, though that linkage doesn't occur at this stage, just the checking.
2. The second point is when you create the pipeline state, where you must include the dynamic library in the `preloadedLibraries` field of the pipeline descriptor. This time, the dynamic library is not a dummy but the real library you plan to use, as it will be linked with the executable during pipeline creation.